# How is this function from google maps API working?

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps

I'm defining the function and the variables, but I'm not actually calling anything. I feel like I'm missing some essential concept because I don't understand how my local server can show a map, along with the marker attached to it when I never specified for it to be called. Can someone help me understand how this works?

Even if the function initMap() was automatically called somehow, how does it know how to create a map and marker if I never call or return the variables map and marker?

javascript:

```
var map;
var myLatlng;
function initMap() {
  myLatlng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom: 4
  });


  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Click to Zoom'
  });

}
```

html:

```
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="index_wrapper">
  <div id="map">
  </div>
</div>
```

Sass:

```
#index_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  #map {
    height: 70vh;
    width: 50vw;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are creating a map and a marker... The Map and Marker objects are created with the `new` command, and they draw a map and a marker when being created

Comment: You must be calling the `initMap` function somewhere...

Comment: How are you including the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are populating your div with id 'map' using this code:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
```

and the marker is created on that map with the code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Click to Zoom'
});
```

I can't help you with why the initMap function is called without seeing more of your code.

Comment: just realized there was a callback in the script tag when I copied/pased javascript google map API. Didn't realize that markers could be created that way too.